# can i run two classes in one python code using python threading?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, oop, python-multithreading

i try this code for understand threading in python but i run this code it always show thread 1 details only. why ? how i fix this

hear is the code

```
import threading
import time

class app1(threading.Thread):
    def server1():
        for i in range(100):
            print ("thread 1")
            time.sleep(1)

class app2(threading.Thread):
    def server2():
        for i in range(100):
            print ("thread 2")
            time.sleep(1)

t1 = app1.server1()
t2 = app2.server2()

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it but unfortunately you are using threads incorrectly. This version would work.

```
import threading
import time

class app1(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        for i in range(100):
            print ("thread 1")
            time.sleep(1)

class app2(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        for i in range(100):
            print ("thread 2")
            time.sleep(1)

t1 = app1()
t2 = app2()

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

I do recomend you folow some tutorials on python mutithreading for example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_multithreading.htm and read the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading

Comment: Thank you @carlos your first link is broken i think this is you think https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: @wisnshaftler Thank you for spotting that, I fix the link :)